# Creating PendingIntent inside BroadcastReceiver's onReceive()

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Have a `BroadcastReceiver` which I want to create a `PendingIntent` inside the `onReceive` method

```
public class MyPushNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
..
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // How to start a PendingIntent here?

    }
```

Most of the doc from Google is not starting within the `onReceive` method, so any sample cod e I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a sample code which uses a pending intent in broadcast reciver   pls check

```
    public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Restart service every 30 minute
private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 30 ;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Start 30 seconds after boot completed
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
    //
    // Fetch every 30 seconds
    // InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
    service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);

    // service.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
    // REPEAT_TIME, pending);

}
     }
```

this code is from vogella ...